# Select automatically a filter option after my page is loaded

Tags: javascript

I have a list of options which filters a range of pictures when the user click on it.

My page loads all pictures (there are lots of them to show together) and I would like to "simulate" a click on "Best Pictures" link to show only this gallery after the page is loaded.

```
<ul id="filters" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
   <li class="type-work">Category</li>
   <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".best">Best Pictures</a></li>
   <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".beach">Beaches</a></li>
   <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".snow">Ski stations</a></li>
   <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".park">Parks</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose the best selector for "Best Picture". 
 ==> select by  `data-option-value` attribute is suitable .

## Filtering during loading page :

```
   $(function(){
      // hide all
     $('[data-option-value=".best"]').hide();
        // show the first 9 items : 
     $('[data-option-value=".best"]:lt(10)').show(); 
   });
```

Comment: Thanks Abdennour, but I'd like to filter during the load... without having to click anything. My page loads all pictures (more than 50) and I'd like show only 9 of "Best Pictures" right after load finishes. Tks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
document.getElementById("myFilter").click();
```

Or:

```
document.querySelector("[data-option-value=\u0022" + chosenFilter + "\u0022]").click();
```